# JS Funtion Not Working

Tags: javascript, php

i am using JS to store values with out the need to click button below is the code but it is not working can you please tell me what is the issue:

```
<input type="text" name="pr" value="<?php echo $rowi; ?>" size="6" onchange="javascript:updateremain(this.value,<?php echo $rowc; ?>);" >

function updateremain(remain, id){
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","adminsort.php?prid="+remain+"&catname="+id,false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

when i run adminsort.php from URL it is working fine.

Comment: have you checked your browser console to see if the function fires? or if you have syntax errors that prevent the js code to fully execute?

Comment: Where is your callback for reasdyState = 4

Comment: yes it is showing correct with the correct values too, but it is not redirecting it think.

Comment: Hi TCR - you may need to put the script in a <script> tag to tell the browser to execute it as JavaScript.

Comment: yeah it is already in script tag!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire `updateremain` function whenever the values changes, you should use: `oninput`, otherwise, using `onchange` the event gets fired when the [input loses focus](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

Also, the `javascript:` is not necessary to declare before the function call.

Answer (score -1):

try using onblur event instead of onchange